# How do I create a query in MS Access that finds and displays parents from the same table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access table, which contains information about individuals within households. I need a way to link the adult record to the child record. These are literal parent/child records, but all held in a single table. The parent/child records share the Household_ID field. Assume at this stage that each household has 0,1 or 2 children and 1 or 2 adults. I can work on the more complex scenarios, just need to know where to start! Thanks for your help.

For example:

```
Person_ID   Household_ID   Age  Gender
1           1              8     F
2           1              42    M
3           1              44    F
```

So for this household I'd like:

```
Household_ID   Child_Age  Child_Gender   Adult_M_Age   Adult_F_Age
1              8          F              42            44
```

Comment: You have no connection between the records.  You need rules to determine who the children are.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. The connection would be household ID. A child is anyone with age <18, parent is anyone over 18 in the same household (more complex rules apply for the live data, so that's an oversimplification just so I can try to get my head around how to link a table to itself).

Comment: And what would the results look like if there were multiple children?  Would you have a row if there are no children?

Comment: If no children, the household would be excluded (that can be done through a simple select query to start with, I guess). If multiple children, each child would be a new record.
So... child 1 | Adult_M | Adult_F
child 2 | Adult_M | Adult_F 
(I know adult_M and adult_F would appear in multiple records; children each appear in a single record).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when gender = 'M' and age >= 18 then age end) over (partition by household_id) as adult_m_age,
             max(case when gender = 'M' and age >= 18 then age end) over (partition by household_id) as adult_f_age
      from t
     ) t
where age < 18;
```

EDIT:

In MS Access, you would phrase this differently.  One method uses subqueries;

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 t2.age
        from t as t2
        where t2.household_id = t.household_id and
              t2.gender = 'M' and
              t2.age >= 18 
       ) as adult_m_age,
       (select top 1 t2.age
        from t as t2
        where t2.household_id = t.household_id and
              t2.gender = 'F' and
              t2.age >= 18 
       ) as adult_f_age
from t
where age < 18;
```

Comment: Thank you - that's really helpful.

Comment: @RichardBeesley . . . I added a version that should also work in MS Access.  I don't recall this question having that tag when I originally answered.

Comment: Thank you. I did include the tag originally; not sure why it didn't show. But this is really helpful. I translated the original code, but not as successfully as your version.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation, apply your criteria to detect member's role. For example using  Age-based criteria

```
select Household_ID,
   max(case when Age < 18 then Age end) as Child_Age,  
   max(case when Age < 18 then Gender end) as Child_Gender,
   max(case when Age >= 18 and Gender ='M' then Age end) as Adult_M_Age,
   max(case when Age >= 18 and Gender ='F' then Age end) as Adult_F_Age
 from tbl
 group by Household_ID
```

Comment: Thank you @Serg. That's very helpful.